# Code in header files will always be inlined?

Tags: c++, inline

I just had a discussion with a coworker concerning code in header files:

He says that code defined in header files will always be inlined by the compiler (like the code from the function GetNumber() in my example header). I say it will be inlined sometimes, whenever the compiler decides to do so. So which one of us has to bring a cake to work for telling filthy lies? Or maybe we are both wrong...?

MyClass.hpp

```
   class MyClass
    {
    public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();

    int GetNumber() const 
    {
     //...; 
     return m_number;
    };

    private:
    int m_number;
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for all the good answers. This certainly helped me and my coworker to clarify this topic. We can't decide who has to bring the cake, though... ;-)

Comment: Would you agree that inlineing do not depends on if the function is defined in a header or not?

Comment: Yes, I agree, with a comment: You really have to be careful what you are talking about if you use the term 'inlineing'. If you define a member function inside a header file, it _will_ be an inline function (place of definition matters). If this inline function will latter be inlined is, as you pointed out, up to the compiler (place of definition doesnt matter). I think Mattis answer is a good explanation of that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any function defined within the class (like your GetNumber example) rather than just declared  is implicitly `inline`. What that means is that it's equivilent to using the `inline` keyword, so multiple inclusions of the header will not cause link errors due to multiple definitions of those functions.

Most modern compiler treat `inline` as a linkage command and nothing more. Some compilers provide stronger keywords such as CL's `__forceinline` which mean 'inline this if it's possible to do so'.

So you're both right and both wrong to a degree.

Comment: `so multiple inclusions of the header will not cause link errors due to multiple definitions of those functions.` What if compiler don't decide to substitute the inline function? Does it still causing linking error?

Comment: Marking the function `inline` causes the compiler to not omit an error if it sees multiple identical definitions of the function regardless of whether or not the compile chooses to inline the code.

Answer (score 7):

Your pal is wrong, you're right.

Inlining do not depends on where the code is (header or not). After preprocessing there is no headers or non-headers. Whole unit is a single file, it contains all included stuff.

Try running gcc preprocessor then you will see:

```
gcc -E some_source_file_with_includes
```

Comment: Inlining does depend on where the code is. If the source for a function is declared in another translation unit it can't be inlined because the compiler can't see the definition, unless you have a compiler/linker that supports whole program optimization.

Comment: +1: liked your comment about the whole unit after preprocessing

Comment: I wrote about HEADER FILES, there is no difference if the definition is inside a header or not. Read carefully.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on what you mean by "inlining". If something is defined in a header file, it will be compiled separately into each compilation unit that includes it. Whether any *calls* to the function will be inlined will be up to the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Actually both are correct. The way you guys meant is bit different. (*I guess)*

From the C++ standard doc for inline function,

> 1. A function declaration (8.3.5, 9.3,
>      11.4) with an inline specifier declares an inline function.
>
> **2. A function defined within a class
>       definition is an inline function.**

So as your colleague said, it **is indeed inline function** .

But **the code substitution** for the inline function instead of the normal function call **is dependent on the compiler**. (*I hope this is what YOU mean*) Even if the compiler doesn't substitute it is still an inline function.

Hope it clears your concern..

Comment: Inline function doesn't have to be inlined, non inline function can be inlined. Compiler decide. Besides, you are talking about specifics of the example not related to the question.

Comment: @adf88, that's what i meant. The code substitution is decided by the compiler but the function is indeed an inline function. All inline functions need not be code substituted by the compiler..

Comment: The question in not about if the funcion is inline function (in C++ language manner). It is about if the function will be inlined by the compiler.

Comment: @adf88, Ahh.. I'll explain in your terms. A fuction defined within a class definition is inlined always (in c++ language manner) but whether it will be code substituted is decided by the compiler.. Am I clear now atleast ?? :)

Comment: +1: you answer did clear up some things for me. You got it right, that we both talked about different things. Thanks

Comment: You right, but this is not answer to the question. The question is about header files, not about classes.

Comment: @ adf88, So what about the example he gave? Isn't class or just header files? C'mon.. It is a valid answer IMO.. In his opinion too..

Comment: If so, the question is terribly formed. "He says that code defined in header files will always be inlined by the compiler" - that's very clear to me. There is no word about classes. You are saying that this is not about header files. Then is it really answer to that question? Maybe the author didn't meant header files, but that's the question he asked.

Comment: The same case is with "inlined by the compiler" and "inline function". Even if he meant about inline functions, he asked about inlineing by the compiler.

Comment: I have to admit that my using of the phrase 'inlining/inline' in my question is not 100 % clear and might be inconsistent. But you live and learn...

Answer (score 2):

***Class member function defined*** (as opposed to only *declared*) in the class' definition are ***implicitly*** `inline`. Other code in headers is not.

You can easily check this: Create a small C++ project with a header and two implementation files, define a function

```
void print(std::ostream& os)
{
  os << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

in the header and include that header in both implementation files. The linker will now complain that the function is defined twice. Put an `inline` before the function definition and the error will disappear.

There are, however, a few more irregularities. For example, a constant definition will automatically get external linkage. Therefore, a

```
const int answer = 42;
```

in a header will not make the linker complain about multiple definitions of `answer`, while

```
int question;
```

will.

Answer (score 1):

That's not true, only code in member functions will be inlined (should the compiler decide to do so) if specified within the class declaration. It must allow the members to be defined though, so they might be declared as the equivalent of C's `static` (which will allow it to be used within the compilation unit, but cannot be linked to other object files), which will put one version in each object file. Try it yourself, you'll notice that unless you specify the inline keyword for anything outside the class declaration, you'll get duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler decides. Even using `_inline` only tells the compiler you prefer inline code, but the compiler's cost/benefit analyser can decide otherwise.

You can use `_forceinline` if you're using [Microsoft C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88%28VS.80%29.aspx) to make the code inline, but that could result in larger binaries.